# How to use different network interfaces for different users?

Tags: networking, centos

I am running a CentOS 8 server where I have a VPN interface `tun0`, I also have a user `vpn`. What I want to do now, is to make sure that the only possible network to use for `vpn` is `tun0`. For **all** of the other users on the server, the default interface should be `enp1s0`.

So when I later start running applications as the `vpn`-user, they will all use the vpn-tunnel. If the tunnel goes down, all of these applications loses network connection.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like:

```
iptables -A OUTPUT ! -o tun0 -m owner --uid-owner 1001 -j DROP
```

where `1001` is the user id of `vpn`.

Translate `iptables` into whatever firewall you're using on CentOS 8.